# Rails dont send 1 field in mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am sending contact email with params from form that user fills. Controller looks like this:

```
  name = params[:contact][:name]
  email = params[:contact][:email]
  message = params[:contact][:messsage]
  product = params[:contact][:product_name]
  ContactMailer.contact_email(name, email, message, product).deliver
```

And it works, it saves ALL the fields to the database and sends the mail, but in the mail, 'Message' field is blank. Here is my mailer.rb file:

```
class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default to: 'my@gmail.com'
  def contact_email(name, email, message, product)
    @name = name
    @email = email
    @message = message
    @product = product
    mail(from: email, subject: `New Order`)
 end
end
```

And my email.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>New Order from <%= "#{ @name }" %></h1>
  <p>Name: <%= "#{ @name }" %></p>
  <p>Email: <%= "#{ @email }" %></p>
  <p>Product: <%= "#{ @product }" %></p>
  <p>Message: <%= "#{ @message }" %></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have a typo here: `message = params[:contact][:messsage]`

Comment: Oh thank you, I checked this like 100 times :)